# CosmosDB size too big

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

can someone help me to analyse the data size for CosmosDB

1. I upload my data from JSON file
2. Single Region
3. I use CosmosDB SQL API for this DB

there are 95969 rows/documents

this is what I have as document  704b

the only vary as size "CityName": "Carleton Place"
however the JSON data file is 26.7MB

**this gives 64MB 
How come they inflate with 32MB???** 
**index OK 15.45MB I have spatial points**

```
  {
      "agegroup": 2,
      "locationgeometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [   45.14478,  -76.14443 ]
       },
       "ProvinceAbbr": "ON",
       "age": 34,
       "LHIN_LocationID": 11,
       "Latitude": 45.14478,
       "Longitude": -76.14443,
       "PostalCode": "K7C 1X2",
       "CityName": "Carleton Place",
       "CityType": "D",
       "ProvinceName": "Ontario",
       "id": "3e496a96-db77-4535-b73b-5ab317b44231",
       "_rid": "sGVsAMC4X4ICAAAAAAAAAA==",
       "_self": "dbs/sGVsAA==/colls/sGVsAMC4X4I=/docs/sGVsAMC4X4ICAAAAAAAAAA==/",
       "_etag": "\"0000cd97-0000-0200-0000-5d586f650000\"",
       "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1566076773
   }
```

[image]

**The JSON file  26.7MB created from MS SQL** 
[image]

**the original MS SQL store 18.94MB with 2.5MB index**
[image]

Comment: Not sure but all the fields are indexed in cosmos db so it would probably increase the data size ?

Comment: @Thomas Don't think that's the case since the index size is a separate metric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a SQL api, cosmosdb container with 6 logical partitions and each partition is about 15 MiB ( that is Million bytes not Mega - 1024*1024 bytes ). 
That is 85 Mega Byte.
Using the [DTUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#Install) tool to export the container to jsom dump, the text dump file size is 48.74 MB

Part of the overhead is CosmosdB's internal fields that are stored in CosmosDB but not part of user data and thus not part of export. Example fields ( you can see them in data explorer )

- _rid
- _self
- _etag
- _attachments
- _ts

There are other overheads not seen in data explorer.

Anywai you should not be too concerned about the size - as most of your cost, typically will be RU ( usage, provisioned ).

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, I came to same conclusion, that is the correct answer.

Comment: Hi Sumit did you explore the serverless option some people say this is 5000RU/s max is serverless only for development?

Comment: @ValentinPetkov It is in preview now, so no SLA yet but even when it goes to GA, it is expected to have higher latency for performance. Usually not meant for production, but if your [usecase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless#use-cases) calls for it you can use it. And correct the current size limit is 50 GB - and that means it is capped at 5000 RU/s. Another (obvious) point is that you cannot specify RU for serverless containers

Comment: The other drawback, can not use Data Migration tool to import data, there is interface 2M file which is taking me so much time to upload I will pause again , this preview take so much time, the latency if I am able to do it 30ms I am OK, but 5000RU  if the query takes 10-15 not good that is only ~500user/s